# How to use form selection value in another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have very simple page in HTML/PHP in which I am displaying form like below

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header" style="background: #095077; color: #fff" >
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="formModalLabel" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">Compare Numbers
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="demo-form" class="mb-4" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="form-group row align-items-center" style = "margin-bottom:20px">
        <label class="col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right mb-0">Number 1
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <select name="number1" id="number1" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">--Select 1st Number--
            </option>
            <?phpwhile($number_row=mysqli_fetch_array($number_result)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $number_row['number'];?>">
              <?php echo $number_row['number'];?>
            </option>
            <?php}?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <label class="col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right mb-0">Number 1
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <select name="number2" id="number2" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">--Select 2nd Number--
            </option>
            <?phpwhile($number2_row=mysqli_fetch_array($number2_result)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $number2_row['number'];?>">
              <?php echo $number2_row['number'];?>
            </option>
            <?php}?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='details.php?id='" class="btn btn-primary">Compare
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want pass `number1` and `number2` value with `details.php` when user press `compare button`. I do not know how I can use selection value from form. Let me know if someone can help me for do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. Simplest way is, You can use the action attribute in the form and use submit button to submit the values to details.php

```
    <form id="demo-form" class="mb-4" novalidate="novalidate" action='details.php' method='GET'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Compare</button>
```

in details.php you will get the submitted values. Now by Capturing the submitted Form Data in details.php, compare the values and respond back with resultant html.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for Your answer, but if I do like that, my button not working. Thanks

Comment: I have button out side of my form, is the issue?

Comment: yes. If you want to put the button outside, you can use the js function to submit the form on button click.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I have added it in form and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript;

But I think it's better to do with form-submit:

At first, change

```
<form id="demo-form" class="mb-4" novalidate="novalidate">
```

to

```
<form id="demo-form" class="mb-4" novalidate="novalidate" action="details.php" method="get">
```

Then you can change the button to a submit button instead of normal button:

```
<input type="submit">
```

So you are able to get the params of your form to details.php. It will call details.php?number1=2&number2=3

In your details.php you can get the values with PHP using $_GET['number1'] and so on..